# IOS 8 and dialog boxes

Tags: ios, xcode

i have an app that i acquired (did not write myself). I am VERY new to IOS and xCode programming, but have been able to slug my way through a lot of the issues in the past 15 months.

Moving the app onto an IOS 8 platform has me totally stumped. My dialog boxes are the wrong size, Facebook login is sideways, twitter login is sideways, etc.

I *think* it is all related to the change Apple made with orientation, but i have no way to verify it or to figure out how to fix it in my code.

I know this is a stretch, but does anyone have a simple recipe to get IOS 8 to function like IOS 7 in regards to orientation of dialog boxes, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be converting all pages to auto layout. It will allow all the controls to adapt to current size (and orientation) of the device. There were some improvements in iOS 8 that are worth learning.

Comment: i understand the auto layout functionality, but i think the problem is that my app is landscape, and the OS thinks i am in portrait?